# i cant delete the model object in django and the delete functionality is not working?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

what i did was i created a modal from bootstrap and attached a confirm delete button and when clicked passes the pk of the item and in the view section, i created a delete view which has these parameters,

```
def DeleteMask(request,pk):
obj=models.Masks.objects.get(id=pk)
obj.delete

return render(request,'main/index.html')
```

so when i render the main page again the item is still there and it is not gone,can someone explain what i did wrong?

```
path('delete/<int:pk>/',views.DeleteMask,name='delete')
```

and this is m button to delete which is present in a modal

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{%url 'delete' pk=mask.id%}"></a>
```

Comment: `obj.delete` is a method you need to _call_ it `obj.delete()`...

Comment: its confirmed iam dumb!

Comment: No need to be harsh on yourself, all of us have days where we make such silly mistakes :) (although a good IDE would have prevented this with some warning like this line has no effect or so)

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the delete function
It should be `obj.delete()` instead of `obj.delete`

```
def DeleteMask(request,pk):
    obj=models.Masks.objects.get(id=pk)
    obj.delete()

    return render(request,'main/index.html')
```